# Skipping "middle" Optional Arguments

Tags: function-construction, optional-arguments

Is there a way to call a function where the "*middle*" arguments should use their default value while specifying values for the "*right-most*" arguments? For example, given this function:

```
f[a_String: "a", b_String: "b", c_String: "c"] :=  a<>b<>c
```

you can leave off the last argument, so `f["x","y"]` returns `"xyc"`. I would like to call `f` in a way like `f["x",,"z"]` to use the default second argument and return `xbz`, but this syntax doesn't work. Is there a (non-contrived) way to do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's yet another way that I just discovered:

```
ClearAll[f]
Default[f, 1] = "a"
Default[f, 2] = "b"
Default[f, 3] = "c"
f[x___, Null, y___] := f[x, Default[f, Length[{x}]+1], y]
f[a_., b_., c_.] := a <> b <> c
```

Here are some examples, tested with Mathematica 8.0:

```
{f[],f[Null],f[,],f[,,]}
(*
==> {abc,abc,abc,abc}
*)
{f["A"],f["A",],f["A",,]}
(*
==> {Abc,Abc,Abc}
*)
{f[,"B"],f[,"B",]}
(*
==> {aBc,aBc}
*)
f["A",,"C"]
(*
==> AbC
*)
f["A","B","C"]
(*
==> ABC
*)
```

Here's how it works:

- If you don't provide an optional argument in your call, Mathematica supplies it from the corresponding `Default` assignment.
- If you omit an argument in between, `Null` is passed, and you match the first definition, which explicitly replaces that `Null` by the corresponding `Default` value. If there's more than one `Null` value, the process repeats until all `Null` values are replaced.

Answer (score 17):

Define function with `Null` inputs

```
Clear[f]

f[a_String: "a", Null, c_String: "c"] := a <> "b" <> c;

f[Null, b_String: "b", c_String: "c"] := "a" <> b <> c;

f[Null, Null, c_String: "c"] := "a" <> "b" <> c;

f[a_String: "a", b_String: "b", c_String: "c"] := a <> b <> c;

{f["x", "y", "z"], f["x", "y"], f["x", , "y"], f["x"], f["x",], 
 f[, "x", "y"], f[, , "x"], f[], f[, ]}

(*  {"xyz", "xyc", "xby", "xbc", "xbc", "axy", "abx", "abc", "abc"}  *)
```

Comment: Yeah, this works, but not quite as *clean/concise* as I was hoping. This will become especially verbose if there are more arguments, or if the function body is longer.

Comment: An alternative is to define something like `f[a_, Null, c_] := f[a, "b", c]`; that way you don't have to repeat the body of the function.

Comment: @2012rcampion Beat me to it by seconds!

Answer (score 10):

We can use `BlankNullSequence` to keep from listing all possibilities of missing arguments. We can use recursion `f[a_]:=f[b]` to keep from having to repeatedly write the function body.

```
f[a___, Null, b___] := 
  (* pair inputs with defaults *)
  Transpose[{
     {a, Null, b},
     {"defaultA", "defaultB", "defaultC", "defaultD"}
  }]//
  (* input or default? *)
  # /. {
    {Null, default_} :>  default,
    {input_, default_} :> input
  }& //
  (* call function with good arguments *)
  Apply[f]

f[a_String,b_String,c_String,d_String]:= a<>b<>c<>d
```

Actually, that may have problems if the inputs involve lists rather than just strings. This should be better.

```
f[a___, Null, b___] := 
  (* pair inputs with defaults *)
  Transpose[{
     {a, Null, b},
     {"defaultA", "defaultB", "defaultC", "defaultD"}
  }] //
  (* input or default? *)
  Map[If[First@#===Null,Last@#,First@#]&] //
  (* call function with good arguments *)
  Apply[f]

f[a_String,b_String,c_String,d_String]:= a<>b<>c<>d
```

When we pair the inputs with the defaults, we need to make sure there are enough inputs. We can use `PadRight` to indicate that optional arguments to the right have been omitted.

```
f[a___, Null, b___] := 
  (* list default values *)
  {"defaultA", "defaultB", "defaultC", "defaultD"} //
  (* pair inputs with defaults *)
  {PadRight[{a, Null, b}, Length@#, Null],#}& //
  Transpose //
  (* input or default? *)
  Map[If[First@#===Null,Last@#,First@#]&] //
  (* call function with good arguments *)
  Apply[f]

f[a_String,b_String,c_String,d_String]:= a<>b<>c<>d
```

Answer (score 7):

When you omit a parameter in the middle then `Null` is passed.  You can check for this, replace the value with a default value, and continue with the execution.

```
f[x_: "a", y_: "b", z_: "c"] := Module[{}, {x, y, z}]
```

As you already know, this gives you the standard default behaviour. You can omit parameters from the right. The use of `Module` will become clear.

```
{f["i", "j"], f["i"], f[]}
(* {{"i", "j", "c"}, {"i", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b", "c"}} *)
```

We can add a *sub-module* that will check for the nulls and replace them.

```
ClearAll[f];

f[x_: "a", y_: "b", z_: "c"] :=
 Module[{xi, yi, zi},
  (* Default body *)
  Module[{args = {x, y, z}, defaults = {"a", "b", "c"}},
   MapIndexed[
    Function[{item, index}, 
     args[[First@index]] = 
      If[item === Null, defaults[[First@index]], item]], args, {1}];
   {xi, yi, zi} = args;
   ];
  (* Function body*)
  {xi, yi, zi}
  ]
```

There is a duplication of the defaults in the submodule. We can't assign a value to the function parameter symbols so we have to change to some **i**nner symbols `{xi, yi, zi}`.  However, it works as expected.

```
{f["i", "j"], f["i"], f[]}
(* {{"i", "j", "c"}, {"i", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b", "c"}} *)

f["i", , "k"]
(* {"i", "b", "k"} *)
```

This method should work for any combination of omitted parameters.

Hope this helps.