# Skip middle optional arguments

Tags: optional-arguments

Is there a way to skip some middle optional arguments?
For example for this function:

```
f[{a_: 80, b_: 90}, {c_: 30, d_: 20}] := 
 Print["a=", a, ", b=", b, ", c=", c, ", d=", d]
```

Call something like this:

```
f[{(* empty or some symbols*), 3}, {4, 5}]
```

and get the result:

```
a=80, b=3, c=4, d=5
```

P.S. Function will have many parameters and will have complicated form, so the answer described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95407/skipping-middle-optional-arguments) may be not applicable.

Comment: You can prioritize certain arguments/argument sequences using [`Longest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Longest.html). Another option is to explicitly pass `Automatic` or similar to the function, and then do some preprocessing inside the function. But personally, I would strongly consider just passing in all values as named options in cases like these: Then it is trivial to skip arguments, and it is very clear which arguments are assigned for any given call

Comment: Thank you, Lukas, for your response. Can you please explain in more details? You mean I need to do something like presented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/DefineAFunctionWithOptions.html)?

Comment: yes exactly, something like that.